# How do I Make check boxes work like radio buttons?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use radio button functionality on my application but it would be difficult to identify a radio button rather than a checkbox. Can i use a checkbox to act like a radio button such that when one is clicked, the other is unchecked and vice versa?

I tried using the radio buttons but i couldnt make them work in different card views.

Comment: You should just use a radio button. What do you mean by "it would be difficult to identify a radio button rather than a checkbox"? Can you draw a picture of what you want your UI to do?

Comment: Hi, yes you certainly can but the problem is that radio buttons have different functions of checkbox. 
You only can select one choice with radio buttons, and severals with checkbox. It will be an ergonomic problem for users on your app.

Comment: I think check boxes are the best option right now

Comment: Am using two different card views for my result display. if i add a radio group in one it is really tricky to add another radio button in the other card view yet it would still be the same radio group

Comment: http://www.tutorialsmade.com/demo/checkboxes.html   Something like this

Comment: @K15W3G, your example shows exactly what a radio button is supposed to do. They are not in the same radio group, as you can have a single, independent answer for each section. A single radio group would only allow a single answer in that radio group. It may be in the same "form", but not the same radio group. You may want to read up on how radio groups actually work. https://html5-tutorial.net/forms/radiobuttons/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<CheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/chkbox1"
android:onClick="onCheckBoxClick"/>

<CheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/chkbox2"
android:onClick="onCheckBoxClick"/>

// define onCheckBoxClick method on your Activity  

public void onCheckBoxClick(View view){
switch (view.getId()){
case R.id.chkbox1:
    if(checkBox2.isChecked()) {
      checkBox2.setChecked(false);
}
break;
case R.id.chkbox2:
    if(checkBox1.isChecked()) {
       checkBox1.setChecked(false);
}
break;
}
```